# Why is there no output from the While loop in my code, despite everything else working?

Tags: java, while-loop

I made this program in java, on the BlueJ IDE. It is meant to take a number in the decimal base and convert it into a base of the users choice, up till base 9. It does this by taking the modulus between two numbers and inserting it into a string. The code works till the input stage, after which there is no output. I am sure my maths is right, but the syntax may have a problem.

My code is as follows:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Octal
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int danum = 0;
        int base = 0;
        System.out.println("Please enter the base you want the number in (till decimal). Enter as a whole number");
        base=in.nextInt(); //This is the base the user wants the number converted in//
        System.out.println("Enter the number you want converted (enter in decimal)");
        danum=in.nextInt(); //This is the number the user wants converted//

        while ( danum/base >= base-1 && base < danum) {
           int rem = danum/base; //The number by the base//
           int modu = danum % base;//the modulus//

            String summat = Integer.toString(modu);//this is to convert the integer to the string//
            String strConverted = new String();//Making a new string??//
            StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer(strConverted);//StringBuffer command//
            buff.insert(0, summat); //inserting the modulus into the first position (0 index)//

            danum = rem;

            if ( rem <= base-1 || base>danum) {//does the || work guys?//
                System.out.println(rem + strConverted);
            }
           else {
               System.out.println(strConverted);
            }

}
}
}
```

I am very new to Java, so I am not fully aware of the syntax. I have done my best to research so that I don't waste your time. Please give me suggestions on how to improve my code and my skill as a programmer. Thanks.

Comment: use  a debugger to find out yourself.

Comment: ... and in case you're not able to use a debugger, just add some sysout statements to verify e.g. your maths (e.g. while loop condition)...

Comment: The syntax does not have a problem if the code builds and runs.
What examples did you try it with? Print the `base` and `danum` before the while loop to see if they're getting the correct values.

Comment: I'd bet the program exits with an exception rather than normally exiting. I think you're dividing by zero when first testing the while condition. Can you edit your question and add what kind of exception/output you get after running the program?

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1):

Edit (previous answer what obviously a too quick response...)

```
String summat = Integer.toString(modu);
String strConverted = new String();
StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer(strConverted);
buff.insert(0, summat);
...

System.out.println(strConverted);
```

Actually, `strConverted` is still an empty string, maybe you would rather than display `buff.toString()`

But I don't really understand why making all of this to just display the value of `modu`. You could just right `System.out.println(modu)`.

I assume that you want to "save" your value and display your whole number in one time and not each digit a time by line.

So you need to store your number outside of `while` loop else your string would be init at each call of the loop. (and print outside)

So, init your `StringBuffer` outside of the loop. you don't need to convert your `int` to `String` since `StringBuffer` accept `int`
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#insert-int-int-

(You could even use `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer`. It work the same except `StringBuffer` work synchronized
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

Your `if` inside the loop is a specific case (number lower than base) is prevent before the loop since it's the opposite condition of your loop. (BTW : `rem <= base-1` and `base>danum` are actually only one test since `rem == danum` at this place)

so :

```
StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();

if(base > danum) {
    buff.append(danum);
} else {
    while (danum / base >= base - 1 && base < danum) {
        int rem = danum / base;
        int modu = danum % base;
        buff.insert(0, modu);
        danum = rem;
    }

    if(danum > 0) {
        buff.insert(0, danum);
    }
}

System.out.println(buff.toString());
```

I would also strongly recommand to test your input before running your code. (No Zero for base, no letters etc...)

Comment: they are entered by user so lets assume valid values - error checking is missing - doesnt work for 1 and 1 . either

Comment: @Daij-Djan Should be better now :)

Answer (score 0):

2 Things

1. do a lot more error checking after getting user input. It avoids weird 'errors' down the path
2. Your conversion from int to String inside the loop is wrong. Whats the whole deal summat and buff.... :: **modifying the buffer doesnt affect the strConverted** (so thats always empty which is what you see)

try to get rid of this. :)

---

1. error is logic related
2. error is java related

Comment: note: rewrite the whole thing and start on paper. add java to the mix once the algorithm works

Answer (score 0):

Your code has the following problems:

1. Firstly, you have declared and initialized your `strConverted` variable (in which you store your result) inside your `while` loop. Hence whenever the loop repeats, it creates a new string `strConverted` with a value `""`. Hence your answer will never be correct.
2. Secondly, the `StringBuffer buff` never changes the string `strConverted`. You have to change your string by actually calling it.
3. You print your result inside your `while` loop which prints your step-by-step result after every repetition. You must change the value of `strConverted` within the loop, nut the end result has to be printed outside it.